# How to disable jetty 9 logging programmably?

Tags: logging, jetty, slf4j

I'm using embedded Jetty 9, with slf4j.jar in the path.  By default, jetty logs tons of information.

I'd like to disable the logging, or at least change the log level to INFO.  How can I do this in the program (i.e., without putting some xml configuration file)?

Comment: Why avoid XML/properties file? They are right way to manipulate log levels. Programming approach for this is bad because you would need to recompile to change log level!!!!!

Comment: Unless you implement some way for the user to change the level themselves, through a GUI or TUI? You can't say one way or the other what the programmer SHOULD do unless you know HOW they're going to use it.

Answer (score 13):

There is no way using straight slf4j to set the [Logger](http://www.slf4j.org/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/Logger.html) level, as slf4j is just a log facade/routing API.

You would need to rely on the underlying logging implementation to set the logging level on the namespace "org.eclipse.jetty"
Such as:

- If using slf4j-simple.jar, and the [SimpleLogger](http://www.slf4j.org/apidocs/org/slf4j/impl/SimpleLogger.html), then you cannot set the level programmatically, only via System properties once the SimpleLogger is initialized, which is very early in the JVM.
- If using slf4j-log4j.jar, use the [Log4j specific techniques](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4598702/dynamically-changing-log4j-log-level).

```java
org.apache.log4j.LogManager.getLogger("org.eclipse.jetty").setLevel(Level.WARN);
```

- If using slf4j-jdk14.jar, use the java.util.logging techniques.

```java
java.util.logging.LoggerFactory.getLogger("org.eclipse.jetty").setLevel(Level.WARNING);
```

- If using logback.jar, cast the slf4j Logger to the [logback Logger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7967165/how-to-configure-logback-with-java-code-to-set-log-level) and then set the Level.

```java
final org.slf4j.Logger logger = org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger("org.eclipse.jetty");
if (!(logger instanceof ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger)) {
    return;
}
ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger logbackLogger = (ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger) logger;
logbackLogger.setLevel(ch.qos.logback.classic.Level.WARN);
```