# How to set Spring Boot's logging levels programmatically?

Tags: java, spring-boot, slf4j, logback

I know how to set the log level via [environment variables](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34181094/476716) and [application properties](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20485059/476716).

Is there a way to set them programmatically?

I would like to set log levels for particular test classes (which are using `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner` and `@SpringApplicationConfiguration`), but not all of them, and without having a separate properties file for every combination.

I tried [defining a non-lazy bean to add a new `PropertySource` to the environment](https://coderwall.com/p/mm5ihw/how-to-add-custom-property-source-to-spring-s-environment); the method was called but it had no effect.

```
@Bean
@Lazy(false)
public PropertySource testProperties(ConfigurableEnvironment environment) {
  PropertySource properties = new MapPropertySource("testProperties", Collections.singletonMap(
      "logging.level.org.springframework.security", "DEBUG"
  ));

  environment.getPropertySources().addFirst(properties);
  return properties;
}
```

Comment: The only way I know of configured log levels once the logger has been started is via JMX...

Comment: @BoristheSpider That's only available for `java.util.logging`, which spring-boot doesn't use.

Comment: Not true on both counts - Logback and Log4j2 both support JMX and Spring Boot supports JUL if you want it to (but why the hell would you...). You just need to configure the JMX connector in the config file. You don't say which framework you plugged Boot into.

Comment: Bingo. Though I was hoping there was a way to change the properties before the context starts up.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I did say, but via the tags.

Comment: Fair cop - it's well known that developers cannot read.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `@TestPropertySource` on your test classes. Unlike the bean-based approach that you tried, `@TestPropertySource` will add the property source to the environment before the context starts which allows the properties to be picked up when the logging system is initialized.

Something like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(YourApplication.class)
@TestPropertySource(properties = "logging.level.org.springframework.security:DEBUG")
public class YourApplicationTests {
    // …
}
```

Comment: this didnt work for me, I am creating a spring boot library which does not have main springboot application and therefore everything has to be loaded from test class. and somehow I am not able to disable/change logging

Answer (score 1):

Credit to [Boris the Spider](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2071828/boris-the-spider) for the hints.

First, add an element `<jmxConfigurator />` to the logback.xml.

Then, this code will work:

```
@Before
public void configureLogging() throws JMException {
    ObjectName name = new ObjectName(String.format("ch.qos.logback.classic:Name=default,Type=%s", JMXConfigurator.class.getName()));
    JMXConfiguratorMBean logbackMBean = JMX.newMBeanProxy(ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer(), name, JMXConfiguratorMBean.class);
    logbackMBean.setLoggerLevel("org.springframework.security", "DEBUG");
}
```

Sadly, there doesn't appear to be a better way to build the object name: the `Package` hierarchy isn't traversable and the string "default" isn't accessible anywhere I can find.

Comment: I really should have thought of one of these first: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7967165/476716